# Manual response when 2 shapes made of rectangular volumes collide

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics, collision-resolution

I have 2 compound objects made of rectangular blocks. One of them (the one that is moving) has a script that listens to OnTrigger callbacks. What I need is to position the moving compound object on the first compound object to make then not collide but stay in contact.

As an example you can thing of two "spheres" made of blocks. Both spheres are on the floor. Then I move one of the spheres (still on the floor) and I detect that it collides the other sphere, so, I need to push the moving sphere up to make it not collide with the first one but stay in contact.

I have a manual algorithm that make tests on the different blocks of the two groups to push it up enough to make them not collide but it is a bit intensive. Do anybody know if unity physic engine can help here? The main problem is that after I receive the collision I can not move the moving sphere up and recheck manually first of all because there's no Check for rectangles and on the other hand if I want to be notified by the physical engine after I move the moving sphere up (to see if it still collides)I need to wait a new frame which is not feasible in my case.

P.S. I'm using unity engine.

Comment: I am a little confused. So you want one of your objects to stay static (like being part of the floor) and the other to "crawl" on top of the static one when it moves close enough?

Comment: Yes, I have a bunch of different rectangular volumes and I want them not to be colliding with the rectangular volume I am moving. So, when the rectangular volume I am moving collides/penetrates the static ones it should be placed on top of them in order to make the volume do not penetrate the static volumes anymore.

Comment: The difficult part is that it must be done same frame the collision is detected. Take into account that if you just place the moving volume on top of the taller static volumen dected it could still collide with a volume that was on this static volume. This collision will be detected next frame, so, it is not a valid solution.